# python3: can't open file '//filename.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory (in Jenkins docker container, python3 docker container)

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I've been trying to run the script, but I get the error:

```
python3: can't open file '//filename.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

whenever I try.

Does anyone know why the two slashes('//') are appearing before the name of the script, when I am running it in the same dir as the python file?

*It's weird because it can see the file, but the '//' may be preventing the run.*

*For context this is running on a Jenkins container.*

I've been trying to run a python script in in a python container.

What's been ran:

```
# this will build a docker image with a tag using a Dockerfile, in the dir it exists in
dir('jenkins/Docker') {
    docker.build('image_tag', '.')
}
```

This builds successfully and am not having issues with it.

Afterwards I try to use the docker run command:

```
dir('jenkins/Script') {
    sh('ls -la')
    sh("docker run --rm image-tag python $file_name")
}
```

for context the result of the ls -all command:

```
+ ls -la
total 36
drwxr-sr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Mar 30 09:01 .
drwxr-sr-x 9 jenkins jenkins  4096 Mar 29 15:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  5175 Mar 30 09:01 Jenkinsfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 18906 Mar 30 09:01 filename.py
```

I've also tried running `python3`/`python` commands to run the script.
As well as renaming the tags, to no luck.
Also tried this on the server, and exec'd into the Docker container, and get the same issue when I run the commands manually.

Comment: What is the value of `$file_name`?

Comment: What's in the Dockerfile?  What is the "shebang" line in the Python script?  Do you need to set the `WORKDIR` to somewhere other than the filesystem root?  Can you [edit] the question to include the code that actually produces the error (not just the environment in which it is called)?